# Do old cats chase moving objects?

Tags: cats

I know kittens usually like to chase moving objects, how about the old one? Do they also enjoy that?

Comment: Depeds on the kat, as does the kind of object or motion they consider interesting. Ask your cat, when the time comes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, older cats still love to play!  The moving object simulates prey. A cat's natural instinct to hunt, chase, and pounce should never go away.  They will slow down a little as they get older, but they should never lose the thrill of "the hunt."

Sometimes, it's up to us to make sure they don't slow down too much.  We do this by providing different types of stimulation - all types of toys, things to scratch, and places to climb.  Dragging string-type toys or feather wands are a great way to keep your older kitty's body and mind healthy.

Comment: depends on the cat indeed. My 9 year old tends to ignore the expensive cat toys but can be occupied for an hour kicking a plastic bottle cap around the room before getting distracted by a sound or whatever.

Comment: @jwenting Love it!   Typical cat.  Mine love my hair scrunchies!

Answer (score -1):

A healthy cat of any age will likely want to play (come want to constantly) and one form of play is stalking and catching things, if they move it's even better.

Play is not just a kitten thing - is play just a human child thing? No, it is  not.